# Convert IO callback to infinite list

Tags: haskell

I am using a library that I can provide with a function `a -> IO ()`, which it will call occasionally.

Because the output of my function depends not only on the `a` it receives as input, but also on the previous `a`'s, it would be much easier for me to write a function `[a] -> IO ()`, where `[a]` is infinite.

Can I write a function:

```
magical :: ([a] -> IO ()) -> (a -> IO ())
```

That collects the `a`'s it receives from the callback and passes them to my function as a lazy infinite list?

Comment: "Because the output of my function depend not only on the a it receive as input" - unfortunately you can't do that in Haskell, because it's referentially transparent. That is, the output value of a function depends only on the parameters passed to it.

Comment: This is true for pure functions, but because this is in the IO monad I can store state between calls. This is what I am doing manually at the moment and are trying to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it might be enough for your purposes, I think.

```
magical :: ([a] -> IO ()) -> IO (a -> IO ())
magical f = do
   list <- newIORef []
   let g x = do
          modifyIORef list (x:)
          xs <- readIORef list
          f xs   -- or (reverse xs), if you need FIFO ordering
   return g
```

So if you have a function `fooHistory :: [a] -> IO ()`, you can use

```
main = do
   ...
   foo <- magical fooHistory
   setHandler foo -- here we have foo :: a -> IO ()
   ...
```

As @danidaz wrote above, you probably do not need `magical`, but can play the same trick directly in your `fooHistory`, modifying a list reference (`IORef [a]`).

```
main = do
   ...
   list <- newIORef []
   let fooHistory x = do
          modifyIORef list (x:)
          xs <- readIORef list
          use xs   -- or (reverse xs), if you need FIFO ordering
   setHandler fooHistory -- here we have fooHistory :: a -> IO ()
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The `IORef` solution is indeed the simplest one. If you'd like to explore a pure (but more complex) variant, have a look at [conduit](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/conduit-overview). There are other implementations of the same concept, see [Iteratee I/O](https://wiki.haskell.org/Iteratee_I/O), but I found myself *conduit* to be very easy to use.

A conduit (AKA pipe) is an abstraction of of program that can accept input and/or produce output. As such, it can keep internal state, if needed. In your case, `magical` would be a *sink*, that is, a conduit that accepts input of some type, but produces no output. By wiring it into a *source*, a program that produces output, you complete the pipeline and then ever time the sink asks for an input, the source is run until it produces its output.

In your case you'd have roughly something like

```
magical :: Sink a IO () -- consumes a stream of `a`s, no result
magical = go (some initial state)
  where
    go state = do
      m'input <- await
      case m'input of
        Nothing -> return ()  -- finish
        Just input -> do
          -- do something with the input
          go (some updated state)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Control.Concurrent.Chan` does almost exactly what I wanted!

```
import Control.Monad           (forever)
import Control.Concurrent      (forkIO)
import Control.Concurrent.Chan


setHandler :: (Char -> IO ()) -> IO ()
setHandler f = void . forkIO . forever $ getChar >>= f

process :: String -> IO ()
process ('h':'i':xs) = putStrLn "hi" >> process xs
process ('a':xs)     = putStrLn "a" >> process xs
process (x:xs)       = process xs
process _            = error "Guaranteed to be infinite"


main :: IO ()
main = do
  c <- newChan
  setHandler $ writeChan c
  list <- getChanContents c
  process list
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a flaw in the library design to me. You might consider an upstream patch so that you could provide something more versatile as input.